# Как "проглотить" событие мыши в cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d

Ничего не могу найти на эту тему. На всех сайтах пишут про метод `setSwallowTouches`, но он же только для `EventListenerTouch`? Буду очень благодарен, если приведёте фрагмент кода.

Answer (score 2):

Наверно, очень поздний ответ, но всё же.
Для обработки мыши используется EventListenerMouse;
Например у нас есть объект класса Player, который унаследован от cocos2d::Sprite. Мы объявляем в нем:

```
using namespace cocos2d; // или можете писать в коде cocos2d::Event, cocos2d::MouseEvent и т.д.

EventListenerMouse *mouseListener_;
void onMouseDown(Event *event); //если нажата кнопка мыши
void onMouseUp(Event *event);   // если отжали кнопку мыши
void onMouseMove(Event *event); // отслеживаем движение
```

В конструкторе класса Player устанавливаем "Слушатель"

```
mouseListener_ = EventListenerMouse::create();
mouseListener_->onMouseMove = CC_CALLBACK_1(Player::onMouseMove, this);
mouseListener_->onMouseUp = CC_CALLBACK_1(Player::onMouseUp, this);
mouseListener_->onMouseDown = CC_CALLBACK_1(Player::onMouseDown, this);

_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(mouseListener_, this);
```

Далее пишем методы для нашего класса. Например, для движения мыши(функция будет автоматически срабатывать, когда вы двигаете курсором):

```
void Player::onMouseMove(Event *event)
{
EventMouse *eventMouse = (EventMouse*)event;
//Например, каждый раз получаем координаты мыши и присваиваем временной переменной MouseCoordY 
auto MouseCoordY = eventMouse->getCursorY();
}
```

Более подробно можно почитать на
http://amanita-studio.com/ru/articles/read/cocos2d-x-event-listener - Мне это очень помогло.